# How to apply multiple functions to all sheets and then save as one excel workbook

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

So I imported all sheets from an excel file using `pd.read_excel('df.xlsx',sheet_name=None)`.
I have a dict with key value pairs.
In all these sheets there is a table present. I want to make the first column as index and then insert a column from a separate dataframe that I already have.

What is the best way to approach this, should I save all sheets in to dfs individually or is there a way to loop over key value pairs?

| Info | Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First Name |  |  |
| Second Name |  |  |
| Phone |  |  |

And then I wanted to insert a column in all sheets so I was thinking I would use `pd.insert()`

Comment: So the info column is to be set as index in all sheets for Ex, sheet_A, Sheet_B,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have a dict of key, values, where each value is a df, you can iterate over them and first set the index, next create a column based on the other df. Use:

```
for name, df in data.items():

   df = df.set_index('info')
   df['new col'] = another_df['specified col']
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.